# UDP communication delay every second or so (Windows SDK & Mac)

Tags: c, macos, sockets, network-programming, udp

I'm sending packets using UDP protocol from Windows to Mac computer (Windows 10, Mac OS X 10.10). I'm using Windows API on Windows (C++) and GCDAsyncUdpSocket on a Mac (Objective C and C). The frequency that I send is around 100Hz. I'm expecting latency of 10ms, and it really is 10ms on the sending computer. But the receiving part gets delayed every 1 second. So it receives around 100 packets and then there's a delay about 50ms.

I tried dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0) on the Mac side but it didn't help. I tried Wi-Fi, Ethernet, different computers and networks, it didn't help either! Firewalls, Windows Defender are off everywhere. There's always a delay every ~100 packets on the receiving (Mac) side.

I can post the code, but it's really basic.

What can be the problem here? It looks like I'm missing some setting that I'm not aware of!

Comment: I suggest using packet capture software on both sides to try to narrow down which side is introducing the delay.  Also try making the Windows machine send to itself, and to another Windows machine.  Also try using `ping` to make sure you don't see the same problem there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'll try it out and post the results here!

Comment: 'delay about 50ms' - on a typical network and OS stack, that's just noise level.

Comment: I have a realtime software on the same network that is transmitting smoothly without delays. I'm not sure what kind of protocol they're using though.

Comment: UPDATE: I used a sniffer on the Mac side and it seems the packets are being received on time. So something's wrong with the GCDAsyncUdpSocket probably.